# Conversion Failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am running into this issue trying to run a SQL query. Can't figure out where the conversion to "int" is happening. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
SELECT  TOP 100 PERCENT 
        a.S1 as "SegNumber", 
        a.S2 as "SegmentName", 
        a.S3 as "Description",
        a.S4 as "SegmentValue" 
FROM
( 
    SELECT      3 as "S1", 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(b.SUMMARY_ACCT)) + '_' + 'Accounts' as "S2", 
                b.ACCOUNT_DESC as "S3", 
                '^' + LTRIM(RTRIM(c.SUMMARY_ACCT)) + '_' + 'Accounts' as "S4" 
    FROM        TEST.dbo.GLCHARTSUM b 
    inner join  TEST.dbo.GLCHARTSUM c   ON  c.PARENT_OBJ_ID = b.SUMRY_ACCT_ID 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT      3 as "S1", 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(c.SUMMARY_ACCT)) + '_' + 'Accounts' as "S2", 
                c.ACCOUNT_DESC as "S3", 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(convert(varchar(100),b.ACCOUNT))) as "S4" 
    FROM        TEST.dbo.GLCHARTDTL b 
    INNER JOIN  TEST.dbo.GLCHARTSUM c   ON  c.SUMRY_ACCT_ID = b.SUMRY_ACCT_ID 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT      2 as "S1", 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(ACCT_UNIT)) + '_' + 'Unit' as "S2" , 
                DESCRIPTION as "S3", 
                '^' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ACCT_UNIT)) + '_Unit' as "S4" 
    FROM        TEST.dbo.GLNAMES 
    WHERE       POSTING_FLAG ='S' 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT      2 as "S1", 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(ACCT_UNIT)) + '_' + 'Unit' as "S2", 
                DESCRIPTION as "S3", 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(ACCT_UNIT)) as "S4" 
    FROM        TEST.dbo.GLNAMES 
    WHERE       POSTING_FLAG ='P'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT      3 as "S1", 
                MATRIX_CAT + Substring(MX_VALUE,1,5) AS "S2", 
                MX_VALUE as "S3", 
                ACCOUNT AS "S4" 
    FROM        TEST.dbo.GLACCMXVAL b 
    INNER JOIN  TEST.dbo.GLCHARTDTL c   ON  b.OBJ_ID = c.OBJ_ID 
) a 
WHERE   1 = 1 
ORDER BY a.S2
```

Error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '^ASSETS_Accounts' to data type int.

Comment: Okay, that's a totally unreadable mess... I'm not even going to try and decipher that.  You should edit and repost with your SQL properly formatted.  But the error message tells you exactly where the problem is.  What type is that ASSETS_Accounts column in the database?

Comment: I assume it has something to do with your S4 column not being the same type across all of your `UNION ALL`'s...  You really need to work on formatting your code.

Comment: @pmbAustin the ACCOUNT column is pk, int, not-null)

Comment: @rs. It's a `VARCHAR` value, not a column.  It's referencing one of his `'^' + LTRIM(RTRIM(c.SUMMARY_ACCT))` columns.  Which leads me to believe the last `UNION ALL` `ACCOUNT AS "S4" ` - ACCOUNT must be an `INT`, which is breaking his `UNION`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this error is because of your last `UNION ALL`.  `ACCOUNT` is an `INT` value, but the other `S4` columns are `VARCHAR`.

You should cast your `ACCOUNT` column to a `VARCHAR`

```
...
UNION ALL 
SELECT      3 as "S1", 
            MATRIX_CAT + Substring(MX_VALUE,1,5) AS "S2", 
            MX_VALUE as "S3", 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR (100), ACCOUNT)  AS "S4" 
...
```